# My iPad is sending out spam emails, what could be the cause?

Tags: ipad, email, security, gmail, virus

My iPad is sending out emails through gMail titled for example CCE29032016_00050. All emails begin with CCE followed by a number. They are sent from myself to myself.

I noticed that it is my iPad because it was sending e-mails from my home IP address (based on Google's activity details), and only my two iPads were connected to the home network at that time (I was not at home).

Has anyone seen these emails before, and how can one stop them from being sent?

Comment: Looks like some kind of technical / log e-mail. What's the contents of the e-mails? Can you make out other receivers than your own account (sent box)? Has your home router been configured to send e-mails in case of log alerts?

Comment: The only content in the email is a dodgy looking attachment (I have seen gif, docx, rar so far). Haven't opened them. The attachment has the same title as the email (plus a file extension). The body of the email says "Sent from my iPhone". I do not actually have an iPhone.

Comment: Upload those attachments to https://www.virustotal.com for malware checking and confirmation. If you have Mac, use a virus scanner to scan the Mac, and if possible the iPad. iOS malware has been creeping up last year, infecting even non-jailbroken Apple devices, e.g. YiSpecter

Comment: Check if the iPad is infected with the YiSpecter malware. See this article for details: http://researchcenter.paloaltonetworks.com/2015/10/yispecter-first-ios-malware-attacks-non-jailbroken-ios-devices-by-abusing-private-apis/ If it is, removal is required, and also change of all passwords on the iPad, e-mail service, and other password-protected services that the iPad has been used for. Basically, all passwords.

Comment: I would even include the router's passphrase and admin password.